# how to put mysql generated values in an php array

Tags: php, mysql

I need to generate an excel report populated from mysql database. I have already made it worked, which generates a report in excel.

But in one column of that report I need to populate the number of pending cases.

**Database Details:**

one h_id has many sl_id.

one sl_id has many pending cases listed as ENUM M,I.

I need to find the total number of rows of pending cases per sl_id.

**Here is my code:**

```
$value = $_POST['hospitalname'];

if($_POST["Submit"]=="Submit") {
        for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($value); $i++) {

$sql = "SELECT sl_id from mfb_servicelog where h_id LIKE ('".$value[$i]."')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$slid = array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if (!in_array($row["sl_id"], $slid)) {
             $slid[] = $row["sl_id"];
        }
   }

   foreach($slid as $id) {

$query = "SELECT info_type from mfb_agent_status_details where info_type = 'M' and sl_id LIKE ('".$id."')";

$resultpending = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($resultpending);
echo "$num_rows\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Above code returns number of pending cases per sl_id together like

```
0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

How to put these to an array so that I can export these to the excel sheet using below code

```
if ($result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error())) {
                while ($rowhos = mysql_fetch_row($result1)) {
                    $hospitalname[$i] = $rowhos;
                    if($i == 0) {
                        $col = 'D';
                    }
                    else{
                        $col = $k;
                    }
                    foreach($rowhos as $cell) {
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowhosname,$cell);
                        $col++;
                    }
                    $rowhosname++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: change `echo "$num_rows\n";` to `$yourArray[] =$num_rows;`?

Comment: Thanks. But can you please tell me... can I do it like $yourArray[$i]... so that I can return each result using echo $yourArray[0]; $yourArray[1]; etc.

Comment: yes, if you use it in a loop, with `$i` incrementing, the `$youArray[$i]` will equate to `$yourArray[0]`/`$yourArray[1]`/etc

Comment: if you see my code I already have a loop for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($value); $i++). Can I use this loop or I have to create another?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume mfb_agent_status_details table has an id attribute (you can use an unique field in the table, maybe it's actually called asd_id for example):

```
$sql = "SELECT mfb_servicelog.sl_id, count(mfb_agent_status_details.*) as count FROM mfb_servicelog LEFT JOIN mfb_agent_status_details ON mfb_servicelog.sl_id = mfb_agent_status_details.sl_id WHERE  mfb_servicelog.h_id LIKE ('".$value[$i]."') GROUP BY mfb_servicelog.sl_id";
```

Now each resulting rows will a "count" attribute that you can insert into the excel.

Comment: My Code:  SELECT mfb_servicelog.sl_id, count(mfb_agent_status_details.id) as count from mfb_servicelog LEFT JOIN mfb_agent_status_details WHERE mfb_agent_status_details.sl_id LIKE mfb_servicelog.sl_id  AND mfb_servicelog.h_id LIKE "42" GROUP BY mfb_servicelog.sl_id;

Comment: Error:  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE mfb_agent_status_details.sl_id LIKE mfb_servicelog.sl_id  AND mfb_servicel' at line 1

Comment: I am not sure why. I modified the query, is it working better ? and does mfb_agent_status_details has an id attribute ?

Comment: just modified it again, I think it was the group by that was wrong.

Comment: ohh I am sorry..mfb_agent_status_details has no id attr.  but it has sl_id

Comment: ah ok, please replace the id by a field that is unique. mfb_agent_status_details.sl_id is not unique so you can't use that.

Comment: I am using info_type...this is where all the pending cases is as enum...and this is the attr. which I need to calculate the total rows.

Comment: I adjusted the query to deal with it, if the syntax is correct it should provide what you need which is the number of pending cases for each sl_id

Comment: Your previous code was also giving out the number of pending cases for each sl_id...Thanks for the code..Can you please also help me out on how to put this to my second code which generates the excel file. Thanks

Comment: maybe put these count into an associative array, with the sl_id as a key and the count as value $pendindCases[$row["sl_id"]] = $row["count"]; then hopefully $rowhos has the sl_id, so you can retrieve the count doing $pendingCases[$rowhos["sl_id"]] and include into the file (for example by making a call to $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue after you looped over $rowhos will add the count in a new column at the end)

Answer (score 0):

You may try php's `explode()` function. The explode() function breaks a string into an array.

Try something like;

```
$str = "0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0";
$array = explode(" ",$str);
```

Hope this helps.